# Change variable in text file according to the different table

Tags: python, jupyter

I couldn't pass difficulty for my graduation project. I have to calculate GPA for all the students in text file. I have a text file and table. I will share the screenshots of the file and table. Firstly, I must change letter grades (such as A,B,C) in the text file. Then I should calculate all these points. I know how to calculate all the grades at the end of the code but I couldn't find the way for change letter grades with points.

Text File : https://i.resimyukle.xyz/QQbbH9.png

Grades :  https://i.resimyukle.xyz/y3dOO7.png

Txt File : https://shrib.com/#lyyExJRaUnyRPTqSZ1KI

I tried to import txt file to jupyter notebook.

I want to share code that I tried but this is very new subject for me so I couldn't wrote a code except import txt file to jupyter notebook with pandas

Comment: please edit your question and paste the `studentsGrade.txt` content in the question

Comment: I added to my question

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. Links to external resources raise the barrier for people to even try to help you, and very often stop working after a while. Here at Stack Overflow, we look for questions which help new visitors over time, not just a quick fix for your immediate problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import re
def determine_grade(score):
    if score == 4:
        return 'A'
    elif score >= 3.70:
        return 'A-'
    elif score >= 3.30:
        return "B+"
    elif score >= 3.00:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 2.70:
        return "B-"
    elif score >= 2.30:
        return "C+"
    elif score >= 2.00:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 1.70:
        return "C-"
    elif score >= 1.30:
        return "D"
    elif score > 0:
        return "D-"
    elif score == 0:
        return "F"

with open("studentsGrade.txt", "r+") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "w+") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            numericGrade = re.findall(r'(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', line)
            alphaGrade = determine_grade(float(numericGrade[1]))
            fout.write(line.replace(str(numericGrade[1]), alphaGrade))
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply but I don't understand why we added out.txt ?